# Ormlite connect to mysql database

Tags: android, mysql, ormlite

I'm trying to connect to mysql database using JdbcConnectionSource in an android application that should use ormlite. I have this method that should connect to the database and create a user table if it doesn't exist:

```
public UserDao() throws SQLException {

    connectionSource = new JdbcConnectionSource("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sell_buy", "root", "");
    utilisateurDao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, User.class);
    TableUtils.createTableIfNotExists(connectionSource,
            Utilisateur.class);
}
```

the problem is that i get a com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure whenever the methood is executed !. I'm pretty sure that the database is running and the information(username and password to connect to the database ) are ok !

I hope someone will help me and thx in advance.

Comment: Title say posgresql, you have tagged as mysql and you are using android for which the only database available is sqlite?

Comment: Sorry for the postgresql i've already changed it xD..i'm using ormlite and trying to connect to a mysql database in the local server (localhost)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i should perform network work in an AsyncTask or a new Thread second to refer the localhost i should use the address 10.0.2.2 since i'm working with the android emulator.

Resolved !